# При использовании margin в % блок вылазит за контейнер

Tags: css

Почему при использовании для элементов списка .list__item margin-left: 5% список .list вылазит за контейнер? Любые другие единицы работают как ожидается.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.logo {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.list__item+.list__item {
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">logo</div>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">item1</li>
  <li class="list__item">item2</li>
  <li class="list__item">item3</li>
  <li class="list__item">item4</li>
</ul>
```

песочница: https://jsfiddle.net/a93podb1/

Comment: Здесь проблема курицы и яйца: маргин 5% зависит от ширины блока, ширина блока зависит от его содержимого, а размер содержимого зависит от маргина 5%, который зависит от ширины блока. Непонятно, как такую бесконечную рекурсию вообще считать, вот и получается что попало

Comment: На практике, если поиграться в песочнице, видно, что браузер решил посчитать ширину блока по содержимому без учёта маргинов и посчитал 5% от этой ширины, вот и получается вылезание